# How can I add a hyperlink to a record of a custom object in LWC?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, datatable, hyperlink

I currently have a custom list view LWC that displays a list of custom objects and its fields. I want to have a hyperlink on a specific field that takes the user to the record page.

So, the html for the datatable looks like this:

```html
<lightning-datatable key-field="Id" data={data} columns={columns}>
</lightning-datatable>
```

Comment: Can you add a little more detail from your javascript controller? I added an answer, but it would be more useful if I could see a few more implementation details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what particular field you are wanting to use to link to the record, but you need two thinks for a link in a datatable -

- A URL Name
- A URL Link

You need to add these after you get your results from the server.

Here is one example:

```
callGetData(yourparam){
  getData({param: yourparam})
  .then(result => {
    let resultList = [];
    result.forEach(r => {
      let record = { ...r };
      //here is the important bit - generating yourUrl and yourUrlName
      record.yourUrl = `/lightning/r/<yoursobjectname>/${r.Id}/view`;
      record.yourUrlName = r.Name;
      resultList.push(childCase);
    });
    this.itemsForCurrentView = resultList;
  })
  .catch(error => {//log error });
}
```

Then in your column definition, you need to reference these values to generate the url link in your table.

```
columns = 
...other columns
{
  label: 'Record Link',
  sortable: true,
  fieldName: 'yourUrl',
  type: 'url',
  typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: 'yourUrlName' }, target: '_blank' }
}
```

One reason NOT to use the `NavigationMixin` is that you can't right click on the record and open in a new tab.

Which is endlessly frustrating for users.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful!